# Some CLSID Registry keys exist but cannot be read

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, registry

I have following program that reads all CLSID registry keys and displays their name on a listbox; it is written in Delphi, but the question is not specific to Delphi; it is rather a question about the Windows Registry.

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  guid: string;
  reg: TRegistry;
  sl: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  name: string;
begin
  memo1.Clear;

  reg := TRegistry.Create;
  sl := TStringList.Create;
  memo1.Lines.BeginUpdate;
  try
    reg.RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
    if reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('\CLSID\') then
    begin
      reg.GetKeyNames(sl);
      reg.CloseKey;

      for i := 1 to sl.Count-1 do
      begin
    guid := sl.Strings[i];

    if reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('\CLSID\'+guid) then
    begin
      try
        name := reg.ReadString('');
      except
        name := '!!! <ERROR1> !!!';
      end;
      reg.CloseKey;
    end;

    memo1.Lines.Add(guid + ' ' + name);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    sl.Free;
    reg.Free;
    memo1.Lines.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;
```

The problem is that following registry keys do exist (they are listed in GetKeyNames), but they cannot be read (reading the default value). I get the Exception "Invalid data type for ''".

The keys which fail are:

```
{33297C9D-2A25-1679-1475-A1CE3901C86D} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
{45049248-47E9-7CEE-A822-1E555F74D237} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
{69C5BE90-E717-97A6-CCEF-C44D93111A5A} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
{8663D540-C578-44AE-9D24-4A9D9A4881C3} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
{9A73B3FA-50DF-3410-930D-51C35FC9237E} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
{EACF7497-3D67-8044-DE95-81429597BB8F} !!! <ERROR1> !!!
```

These keys do not appear in `regedit.exe`, even if I run RegEdit in the NT-AUTHORITY\SYSTEM context (which shows really everything).

Do you have the same problem, or is my registry somehow damaged?

Comment: Use `reg.GetDataAsString('');` to get `non string` datatypes too.

Comment: @bummi, that is a solution for the problem (the exception). Story about registry redirector below is fine but covers just the *"cannot find the key in regedit"* part of the question.

Comment: @TLama Story below covers it all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The obvious explanation is that the keys exist but you look for them in the wrong place. I bet you have a 32 bit process on a 64 bit machine and the keys are redirected by the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx).

Look for the 32 bit CLSID section in regedit under

```
HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID
```

More useful information can be found at [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253.aspx) on MSDN.

Then when you've located the key, it would seem that the default value does not have the data type that you expect. You are expecting a string, but some keys clearly have a different type. You'll need to add some resiliency to your program to deal with that.

Taking your first CLSID, on my machine indeed it is not to be found under `HKCR\CLSID`, the 64 bit registry. But under `HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{33297C9D-2A25-1679-1475-A1CE3901C86D}` is present. And the default value has type `REG_BINARY`.

So, to summarise, here are my conclusions:

- Your registry is fine.
- Your program reads from the 32 bit view, but you have been looking in the 64 bit view in regedit.
- Not all CLSID keys use `REG_SZ` for their default value.

---

Should you decide that you want to read from a different registry view than that matched to your program's bitness, use the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` or `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` flags to specify the view. As detailed in [Accessing an Alternate Registry View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx). In your case you might use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to read from the 64 bit view.

---

As an aside, your `for` loop should start from `0` rather than `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. Yes I am running a 32-bit application (compiled with XE7) on a Win64 PC. I have found these registry keys in the "Wow6432Node" now. I will now use `GetDataAsString` or something similar to handle non-string default-values. (I thought the registry standard defined the default-value to be `REG_SZ` only).

Comment: The default value can store data using the same types as named values